# Yield a dictionary item from generator in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface-datasets

My purpose is to yield a pair of text and label from the huggingface NLP dataset, and pass the text part to a NLP model, and compare the prediction against the existing label of the dataset.

```
pipe = pipeline(model=MODEL, config=MODEL, tokenizer=MODEL)

def data():
    for i in range(100):
        l['text'] = dataset['test'][i]['text']
        l['label'] = dataset['test'][i]['label']
        yield l

print(pipe(data()['text']))
```

Then I got the error "generator is not subscriptable". Can I understand that the generator expect all outputs to be homogeneous?
How can I have the generator in python yield a dictionary item so that I can process the elements differently, like the 'text' and 'label' in the aforementioned case.

Thanks

Comment: `data()` returns the generator object.  Use `for item in data: print(item['text'])` to iterate through the items yielded.

Comment: @MarkTolonen With that, i got an error: "NameError: name 'l' is not defined" inside the data() definition.

Comment: That's because you didn't define `l = {}` in your data definition.  You didn't make a [mcve], so there's no definition for `dataset` or `pipeline` either.

Comment: You don't need `l` at all: just yield `dict(text=dataset['text'][i]['text'], label=...)` directly.

Comment: In addition to what @MarkTolonen advises, you will need to explore how to consume the generator in say a `for` loop or via `next()` as this `data()['text']` will not work but maybe `next(data())['text']`

Comment: @JonSG you're definitely right, my ultimate purpose is not to iterate through a preset number like 100 but rather yield by demand, your solution works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `from_generator` function https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/loading#python-generator

```
from datasets import Dataset

def my_gen():
    abc = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    labels = [1, 0, 1]
    for x, y zip(abc, labels):
        yield {"text": x, "label": y}

dataset = Dataset.from_generator(my_gen)
```

Then you can use the pipeline in the way it's expecting the inputs, depending on the model, most probably it looks something like:

```
from transformers import pipeline

pipe = pipeline(model=MODEL, config=MODEL, tokenizer=MODEL)

# First datapoint
pipe(next(dataset)["text"])
```